# variable not passing value in query though it contains value

Tags: laravel, variables, sum, compare, where-clause

```
 public function Query()
{
    
    $total= User::get('e_id');
  //  dd($total);
    foreach($total as $totals){
     

        [$year, $month] = explode('-', $this->month);
        dd($totals);

        $s= User::whereMonth('date' , $month)->whereYear('date' , $year)->where('e_id' , $totals)->get()->sum('latehours');
        
        dd($s);
    }
  //  dd($totals);

}
```

in this code the variable $totals contain value of 'e_id' e.g. "a-2" which it get from form when I dd($totals) it shows value e.g. "a-2"  but when I compare it with 'e_id' it shows sum null(0) of 'latehours' in the variable $s other wise when I directly put 'a-2' it sum up the record of 'latehours' against this 'e_id'. whats the problem here ? any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$s= User::whereMonth('date' , $month)->whereYear('date' , $year)->where('e_id' , $totals->e_id)->get()->sum('latehours');
```

Your are passing $totals object in where condition change it to $totals->e_id